# Getting ECPoint/ECPublicKeyParameters from byte[] in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

So far I've managed to generate a ECDHE pair in bouncy castle's lightweight API. However I have issues trying to recreate the public key from an byte[].

Since the ECPublicKeyParameters object only has one method getQ() I am assuming thats all that is required to reconstruct the key. The other parameters such as the curve used (P-521) are kept constant.

I am doing the following:

```
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = kpgen.generateKeyPair(); //ECDHE Key Generator

ECPublicKeyParameters pubKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)kp.getPublic();
byte[] aPubKeybytes = pubKey.getQ().getEncoded(false); //Should I set to true or false?
```

Unless there is another way to get the raw bytes of the public key pubKey, I don't see a way to get the bytes without invoking method getQ() which returns an ECPoint object.

My question is how to reconstruct the byte[] into a ECPoint object using bouncy castle's lightweight API. Or, better yet, how to reconstruct the whole ECPublicKeyParameter object using an byte array somehow derived from the original pubKey object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To whomever it may concern I resolved this issue by using the PublicKeyFactory and SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory to encode and decode the key.

Using:

```
byte[] key = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.createSubjectPublicKeyInfo(pubKey).getEncoded();
```

I was able to get the raw bytes of the key.

and using:

```
ECPublicKeyParameters bpubKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.createKey(key);
```

I was able to recreate the public key.